# Using Models and Migrations in Sequelize

Tags: model, sequelize.js

Let's say I'm creating a User model, so I create a migration like this:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      username: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      phone: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING(15),
        unique: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users')
  }
}
```

And this is my User model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

class User extends Sequelize.Model {

  static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return super.init({
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          is: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/,
          notNull: true,
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          notNull: true,
          notEmpty: true,
          max: 15
        }
      }
    }, { sequelize })
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

Which of the column additional properties do I need to put in the Model? For example, I think I can omit the 'allowNull' property in the Model, but as far as I know, if I have a column that is a primary key (other than id), I need to put it in the model.

So which one I should put in the Model and which one should I not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are just a way to version your database schema. It may contain definitions that are not relevant to your business requirements (e.g.: how to auto generate an ID field, timestamp columns, etc.), but everything else should be in the models.

In your example, I don't think Sequelize will allow you to omit `allowNull`, because you have a validation that prohibits null values. Also, if you ever called `sync()` in your model, the table would be created without this constraint.

Regarding the key, unless the database knows how to generate the value for this column, it should be in the model as well.